# How to use different datatype variable based on condition?

Tags: c, types, c-preprocessor

I have following two structure

```
typedef struct {

int day;

char action [10];

}DataType1;
```

and

```
typedef struct {

int day;

char action [50];

}DataType2;
```

Now i have to use only one structure data type based on some condition. I have done something like this

```
void *ptr;
DataType1 var1;
DataType2 var2;

if (validCondition  == true)
{
    ptr = &var1;
}
else
{
   ptr = &var2;
}
//Used ptr in remaining code
```

But using this code i fill that may be there is some design flew in my code that's why i need this type trick but anyway i need that. I thought some different way also but i have doubt how it works

```
if (validCondition  == true)
{
    #define GENERIC_TYPE DataType1;
}
else
{
   #define GENERIC_TYPE DataType2;
}

GENERIC_TYPE myVar;
//use myVar in remaining code
```

As i know line starting from symbol `#` consider as processor command and it will be known and replaced at compile time. But here i have `if` condition in which `validCondition` changed run time and according that `#define` defined.

So in this case how processor will work?

Also any one have batter idea to define different data type variable based on condition?

Comment: Lines starting with `#` are **preprocessor directives**, not processor command. The compiler have completely no knowledge of them because they have been replaced in the preprocessing phase, and in that phase there's no code executing so you can't use an if block like that. If the condition is a compile time constant use `#if`

Comment: Why not just use `DataType2`  exclusively?

Comment: @a3f Point noted..thanks

Comment: Maybe it would help if you described your real problem. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You should add that `DataType1` and `DataType2` come from third-party code and that you cannot change them.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a wrapper type for these data types:

```
struct DayAction {
  int day;
  char *action;
  size_t actionlen;
};
```

Then, have a variable of that type and, depending on your condition, fill in the fields of that variable:

```
struct DayAction day_action;

if (condition()) {
  day_action.day = dt1.day;
  day_action.action = dt1.action;
  day_acion.actionlen = sizeof dt1.action;
}
```

After that, you can operate on `day_action`, since it points into the original data.

If you need to change the `dt1.day`, make `DayAction.day` a pointer.
If you don’t need to change the `action`, make `DayAction.action` a `const char *`.

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping only one `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
    int day;
    char *action;
} DataType;
```

And then based on some condition, invoke `malloc()` with the proper number of bytes you need:

```
DataType dt;
if (checkWhateverCondionYouWant)
    dt.action = malloc(someSize);
```

HTH.

Comment: `s/char action/char action[]/`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion  But unfortunately i can't do it. This structure available in 3rd party source code. So i can't change it.

Comment: @user2520119: So you want to run some pre-processor directive based on some value which will be determined at runtime? eh?

Comment: Edited, is it fine now?